# Python and CGI: Prevent resending form data upon refreshing

Tags: python, html, cgi

I am new to Python (somehow I started looking at python 2 days ago).

I tried to write a simple interactive webpage with CGI, and I used HTML form to get user input. However, as everyone knows, if I refresh the webpage, the form data will be resubmitted again. I just have no idea how to prevent this from happening.

The same problem, but in php/javascript, has been discussed and solutions can be found, but I would like to find the answer to the python case.

I hope there is someone here who can address my problem. Since I am not quite familiar with the language, I hope that, instead of solely giving me a descriptive solution, the kind one can also give me the pieces of codes necessary.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not Python-specific, it's about the general web application design patterns.

1. Use `GET`s for requests that do not change the web app's state (viewing, queries and so on). Render the page in the response.
2. Use `POST` for whatever request that modifies the state (post submitting, editing, deleting).
3. Never render anything in the response, provide a [303 See Other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) redirection to the page where the results of the `POST` can be seen. E.g., if the user added a comment on the page http://example.com/blog/123, the `POST` handler can be http://example.com/submitcomment, but it should return nothing but a redirection to http://example.com/blog/123#comment5.

That's what @mikep referred to as Post-Redirect-Get.

On the related note: do yourself a favor, skip CGI. There is a number of nice and clean web frameworks for Python. Try Flask  or Bottle (smaller frameworks) or go straight to Django if you are building a big app. Search here on Stack Overflow for pros and cons of different frameworks.

Just skip CGI. It's hard to build a good and maintainable CGI app, there are too many things to take care of, things that are already thought if in the frameworks.

I've been wasting time supporting a CGI application for some time, and switching to a framework was a relief.

Comment: I was playing with C++ last year, and python is the second programming language that I know (well, I just started a week ago though). Since the server of my school has a python interpreter that allows CGI, I just want to try both in tandem. I guess I will try Django some time later.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to view these lectures: http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs253/CourseRev/apr2012

Week 2 will address your queries.

Comment: It seems to be a nice reference. Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [POST-REDIRECT-GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) web programming patern.